# Linq remove duplicate optimisation

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I have always been using this technique to deal with duplicates from a `List<T>` using Linq

```
var distrinctPricings = pricings.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValidFrom).GroupBy(x => x.Quantity).Select(x => x.First());
```

The `pricings` collection is a list of custom type not implementing any sort of comparable.

Here I am taking only the most recent princing when there is one with the same quantity.

It works fine but I was wondering if there wasn't a better way to do this because it really feels like a hack imo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question but is there something wrong with [`.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I'm assuming that `pricings` is a collection of a custom type and he hasn't implemented any sort of comparable.

Comment: @Dave a reasonable guess but also easily remedied.

Comment: `pricings` is a collection of a custom type not implementing any sort of comparable. And there is nothing wrong with his line of code. It does exactly what I want. I just want to know if there is a better way to do what this line does. With a comparable maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really think what you have feels like a hack, but since you've mentioned "optimisation", you can certainly improve performance by not doing a sort. You only need one pass through the enumerable:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, Pricing>(): // Assuming .Quantity is an int

foreach(var p in pricings)
{
    if (!d.ContainsKey(p.Quantity) || p.ValidFrom > d[p.Quantity].ValidFrom)
    {
        d[p.Quantity] = p;
    }
}
```

Whether this is really worth it depends on how many items you have in `pricings`. You'd have to profile to find the break-even point, but for a very long enumerable the approach above is more performant than doing a sort.

Comment: The sort is important in that it influences which item is kept if there are duplicates.  If you don't sort the data its effectively arbitrary which is kept, if you do the sort then its well defined.  If you do the comparison for every single duplicate match then you're doing a comparable amount of work as doing a sort.

Comment: @Servy It isn't really arbitrary which one you keep since you only replace the item at the `p.Quantity` index if the `ValidFrom` is greater. See the second clause in the if statement condition. I'm not really intimately familiar with the complexity characteristics here, but I'm fairly certain this is O(N), given that you can take the net work needed to do a comparison against a dictionary element and replace the element as a constant. Doing a sort can't be done in better than O(N logN) on average (or at least, I'm fairly certain `OrderBy` doesn't do better than that).

Comment: @Servy Putting that more simply, doing a sort is an inefficient way to find max value. The fact that we're finding independent max values for each value of `.Quantity` doesn't really change this.